# Why do many polysyllabic adjectives ending in -y often take suffix -er and -est to form comparative and superlative form, rather than "more/most"?

Tags: grammar

In principle, the comparative form of polysyllabic adjectives has "more" before the word, rather than taking a suffix "-er". But why do adjectives ending in "-y" often take the suffix "-er"? For example, "luckier". (and the same for superlative)

Regardless of which from "more lucky" and "luckier" is considered correct, many people use the latter anyway, and it also applies to other words that end with "-y". So why are polysyllabic words ending in "-y" an exception?

Comment: What "principle" are you talking about? I've never heard of any special rule about polysyllabic adjectives.

Comment: The rule I know is 1 syll = *Redder*. 3 syll = *More fantastically*. 2 = Either way depending on habit (**clumsier, funnier, more likely**).

Comment: Bisyllabic adjectives ending in /i/ or /o/ (_easy, narrow_) can take the suffix, though they vary in which is more common. This is an area that's changing, like most English morphology.

Comment: ESL learners are taught a rule native speakers don't know or follow. Native speakers copy what they've heard.

Comment: Can you make what you're really Asking much more clear, most obviously by posting three or four simple examples of complete sentences?